# Can I place more than 2 images on the Native Splash Screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a project where an image would be my background, one would be a logo centered on the screen and another that would be at the bottom of the screen. Can I do this on Native Splash Screen or would I have another way to do this? I managed to make the Splash Screen with the first two images with Native Splash Screen but I cannot add the third image. Example of how it should look:

[image of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57SWB.png)

Comment: use splash screen with background image as first widget in the list and use container with size of height and width of the screen using mediaquery with transparent background as color. after than inside container provide column widget inside there will be two widgets center widget and give second image as a child and finally put align widget with alignment bottom and put third image as a child widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any image editor tool and combine imagem1 and imagem3. then, use this as a background image in

```
flutter_native_splash:
  background_image: assets/background.png
  image: assets/imagem2.png
```

Comment: important note:

you can't use color and background_image together